Conditions for $H = I - 2ww^{*}$ to be unitary
I'm struggling to find my way through this, stuck half way, clearly I'm getting something pretty basic wrong here.
for $H = I - 2ww^{*}$ to be unitary, given $w \neq 0$ a column vector, and where w* denotes conjugate transpose, so in this case a row vector of conjugate elements, we must have $HH^* = I$, therefore we get the condition:
$$ 
I = HH^* = (I - 2ww^{*})(I - 2ww^{*})^* = ... = I - 4ww^* + 4(ww^*)^2
$$
where I used the fact that $ww^*$ is self-adjoint above. simplying:
$$ ww^*(ww^* - I) = 0$$
and since $w \neq 0$ we have $ww* \neq 0$ and so necessarily $ww^* = I$.
But this seems off since, for instance, $ww^*$ would be a rank one matrix and $I$ is full rank, so this cannot be except for the case $n = 1$ no?

Keyword : Householder transformation.

Why does $ww^{\ast}\neq0$ imply that $ww^{\ast}=I$?

I don't understand your last sentence : you can substract a rank-one matrix to a rank-n matrix without any consequence on the dimension...

I got $^∗(^∗−)=0$ hence $ww^* = 0$ or $ww^* - I = 0$ no? in the latter case that means $ww^* = I$ in particular

Note that $$(ww^\ast)^2 = ww^\ast ww^\ast = w(w^\ast w)w^\ast = w\|w\|^2w^\ast = \|w\|^2ww^\ast.$$ With this, we can simplify your equation to $$0 = -4ww^\ast+4\|w\|^2ww^\ast,$$ giving us $\|w\| = 1!$
The reason that your argument $ww^\ast(ww^\ast-I) = 0$ doesn't work is because there are nonzero matrices $A,B$ where $AB = 0$. This type of argument always works with integers and real numbers: if $ab = 0$ then one of $a,b$ are zero, but this is generally false with matrices. Consider, for example, $A=\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&0\end{bmatrix},B=\begin{bmatrix}0&0\\0&1\end{bmatrix}.$

Thank you! I did actually consider this as well, but was bothered that I also found another route to get to the seemingly bogus $^∗(^∗−)=0$ which I'm trying to understand my error with

I just updated my answer to address this! Hope it helps.

aha, right.. the ring of square matrices over $\mathbb{C}$  isn't an integral domain. duh :-) thank you!
